# MPL library integration in iOS. Will it contradict APPLE in app purchase or any other payment rule?

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

We are planning one app with such a concept that consumers can buy service from other user and can pay amount through application itself.

What we are concerned is, will APPLE have any objection if we implement MPL item payment i.e. directly user would be able to buy a service from other user by paying within the application ?

We are referring [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-iOS/) for payment integration

Real world scenario would be like I have a few questions and need help to solve those. Some one will offer help and quote some amount. I should be able to pay amount to that person through the application.

Does this contradict in app purchase or any other rule regarding payment?

Have any one idea about this ? please share thoughts.

Thanks

**Note:** I know the question appear to be offtopic but I have already asked on [paypal forum](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/MPL-library-integration-in-iOS-Will-it-contradict-APPLE-in-app/m-p/840624#U840624) and they are redirecting me here. Also I have posted this on [apple forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1004985#1004985) as well

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policy and not programming

Comment: @CarlVeazey I know, but there must be some place to get an answer for this. Would you please help me where it should be asked as I am not able to get answers on paypal or apple forum also. And they are redirecting me here.

Answer (score 0):

Apple policies seem to apply only to digital goods. Many sellers of physical world goods and services have successfully integrated.

But note that the 'MPL' product you mention is outdated. Instead, check out the newer [PayPal mobile SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/).