# iOS: Integrate PayPal SDK to purchase Items

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I've read this guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies
And seems in point 11.3 "Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected", so, it applies with an app that sells tickets for entries in a music local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected
>
> 11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected

From what I understand. You can use an alternative to IAP. With which you :

- Can't sell *content, functionality, or services* for the app itself ;
- Can sell *physical goods or goods and services* for outside the app.

**Edit :**

You might want to look this Q/A too : [If I use the PayPal gateway in my iPhone app, will Apple approve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005929/if-i-use-the-paypal-gateway-in-my-iphone-app-will-apple-approve-it)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a duplicate of [MPL library integration in iOS. Will it contradict APPLE in app purchase or any other payment rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772307/mpl-library-integration-in-ios-will-it-contradict-apple-in-app-purchase-or-any)

Although if you get the ticket on the device itself, it could be considered a digital good.

Comment: thats the main question: Although if you get the ticket on the device itself, it could be considered a digital good.